# Fetch Element ID of Parent Div Via Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, closest

I have a situation where i need element id of div where action happened.

e.g i have list of dynamically generated answers, within answers there are comments. when i click on remove comment, i need to fetch id of answer, i can fetch id of comment. more detail via code.

e.g there is a core div which is generated dynamically.

```
<div class="ans" id="ans_332">...</div>
```

e.g this a delete comment link

```
<a href="#" class="delcmt" id="cmtid_5432">delete</a>
```

here is jquery code

```
$(".ans").on({
   click: function (e) {
       var id = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
       return false;
   }
}, '.delcmt');
```

i want to fetch element id of selected ".ans" instead of closest div which target comment item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `.ans` class to the `closest` selector:

```
var id = $(this).closest("div.ans").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$(".delcmt").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  alert($(this).closest("div.ans").attr('id'));

}
```

I think this should work if the link is in the answer div.